# Jenkins pipeline using maven project

Tags: docker, maven, jenkins

[image]

I am trying to create a maven project pipeline it show me docker error although i already installed docker integration plugin in jenkins.

Comment: Please post your pipeline code.  Also please post the exact plugin you're using

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: "docker: command not found" You must install docker on the node where this pipeline is running.

Comment: could you please elaborate more " You must install docker on the node where this pipeline is running" what I do is just go manage the Jenkins option and install the docker plugin and that's it? I cant understand about specific node where i install docker plugin